# Celery KeyError: 'tasks.add' when trying to run a simple task

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, redis, celery

I'm trying to run a simple Celery task using Redis on an EC2 instance as the broker and connecting to it from my local machine, but I'm encountering an error when the Celery worker tries to execute the task. The error message is as follows:

```
The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[4, 4], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (81b)

The full contents of the message headers:
{'lang': 'py', 'task': 'tasks.add', 'id': '8f2b3e82-8a3b-4ee3-9038-574931e0022b', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': '8f2b3e82-8a3b-4ee3-9038-574931e0022b', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': '(4, 4)', 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen130049@marlowe.cc.ucsf.edu', 'ignore_result': False}

The delivery info for this task is:
{'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 591, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'tasks.add'
```

I have defined the task in a file called tasks.py:

```
# tasks.py
from celery_config import app
from save_dataframe import save_dataframe
import pandas as pd
    
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

My celery_config.py file is as follows:

```
from celery import Celery

broker_url = 'redis://:password@ec2-...compute.amazonaws.com:6379/0'
result_backend = 'redis://:password@ec2-...compute.amazonaws.com:6379/0'

app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_url, backend=result_backend)
```

I start the Celery worker with the command celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info. When I run my test script, I receive the above error message. I've double-checked my task definitions and Celery configurations, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue.

here I attached the output when starting the worker:

```
celery -A celery_config worker --loglevel=info
 
 -------------- celery@marlowe.cc.ucsf.edu v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.17 2023-03-26 10:42:17
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7f709e0066b0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://:**@...amazonaws.com:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://:**@...amazonaws.com:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 28 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]


[2023-03-26 10:42:18,717: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://...compute.amazonaws.com:6379/0
[2023-03-26 10:42:18,788: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-03-26 10:42:20,117: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-03-26 10:42:20,561: INFO/MainProcess] celery@... ready.
```

Any help in identifying and resolving the problem would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

anyone else facing this problem, i added this to my celery config and it seemed to work:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(['tasks'], related_name='tasks', force=True)
```

Comment: Please post the output when starting the worker

Comment: @itzMEonTV I attached the output for starting the worker - thanks for the quick response and let me know if it helps at all

Comment: how do you call/start it?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
celery -A celery_config worker --loglevel=info
```

to

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```